# Flutter/Firestore - query snapshot does not include all docs

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore query:

```
 FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('collection')
        .withConverter<Model>(
          fromFirestore: (snapshots, _) => Model.fromJson(snapshots.data()!),
          toFirestore: (model, _) => model.toJson(),
        )
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) async {

          int size = snapshot.size;
         items = snapshot.docs.map((e) => e.data()..path = e.id).toList();
    });
```

My collection contains about ~67000 documents, but `snapshot.size` is 1297. The documentation says snapshot should contain **all** docs, so why only 1297 is included?

If I try to use `get()` instead, it will take 5 times longer, but I will get the same 1297  docs as a result.

Any ideas? I need to get **all documents** from my collection.

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-count-the-number-of-documents-in-a-firestore-collection-3bd0c719978f) will help.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how you should count the number of documents in a collection. Why? because you'll have to pay a document for each document you read. The simplest solution would be to use [count()](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/count.html). If this method returns 1297, then indeed there are 1297 documents in your collection.

**Edit:**

To answer your last comment:

> is count() billed?

Yes, according to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#aggregation_queries):

> count() operations that match between 0 and 1000 index entries are billed for one document read. For a count() operation that matches 1500 index entries, you are billed 2 document reads.

So in your case, if your collection contains 1297 documents, you'll have to pay for only two document reads.

Comment: is `count()` billed?

Comment: Yes, but please check my updated answer.

Comment: Actually, I got docs from Firestore cache. Load from server fails with message Firestore query failed with code=RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED. What is correct way to load large collection?

Comment: If you're reading the documents only from the cache, then there is nothing that you need to pay for. Regarding the exception, [here is the reason](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3070) why you're getting it.